# How to store a BLOB containing a null character with Microsoft.Data.SQLite?

Tags: .net, sqlite

I'm trying to store a BLOB in an SQLite database with [Microsoft.Data.SQLite 2.2.6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SQLite/2.2.6).

Here is how I'm doing it:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SQLite" Version="2.2.6" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

```cs
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;

namespace InsertBlobContainingNullCharacter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=Test.sqlite3"))
            {
                connection.Open();

                var create = connection.CreateCommand();
                create.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(file1 BLOB, file2 BLOB)";
                create.ExecuteNonQuery();

                var delete = connection.CreateCommand();
                delete.CommandText = "DELETE FROM test";
                delete.ExecuteNonQuery();

                var insert = connection.CreateCommand();
                insert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test (file1, file2) VALUES (@file1, @file2)";
                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("file1", new byte[] {0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x00, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36}).SqliteType = SqliteType.Blob;
                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("file2", new byte[] {0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36}).SqliteType = SqliteType.Blob;
                insert.ExecuteNonQuery();

                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm storing a `byte[]` containing a null character (0x00) in the `file1` column and it gets truncated. When I try to read the value with the `sqlite3` tool, I see that it is truncated exactly at the null character. As expected, the `file2` column is not truncated:

```
$ sqlite3 Test.sqlite3 "SELECT file1 FROM test" | xxd
00000000: 3132 330a                                123.
$ sqlite3 Test.sqlite3 "SELECT file2 FROM test" | xxd
00000000: 3132 3334 3536 0a                        123456.
```

What I am doing wrong? How am I supposed to store a `byte[]` as `BLOB` without truncation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that my assumption about the data being truncated is wrong. The data is fully stored but the `sqlite3` command truncates it when displaying the result.

Using the `HEX` function demonstrates that everything is fine:

```
$ sqlite3 Test.sqlite3 "SELECT HEX(file1) FROM test"
31323300343536
$ sqlite3 Test.sqlite3 "SELECT HEX(file2) FROM test"
313233343536
```